# Public cannot like posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How should I change my settings to allow public to 'like' my posts? They can 'share' but not comment or like. My setting is public on my wall.

And in my  Followers' settings 'Everybody' is seleted. Ref:following image

[image]

I just want 'like' to be allowed publicly not the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Go to **Settings**.
- Click on **Public Posts**.
- Click on **Public Post Comments**.
- Select the option **Filter Off** from dropdown menu.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  Enabling like will also enable comments.